# how can we calculate a video time?

Tags: .net, asp.net, video

in my application i want to display the duration time of the video ( that is time of the video) in asp.net

Comment: I think that's more a question about how to leverage the API of Windows Media SDK or something like that (example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43208/How-to-get-the-length-duration-of-a-media-File-in-.aspx)

Comment: .swf,.flv,.mpeg,.dat these r the file type and .mp4 also

Comment: I retagged as vb.net, simply because nothing in asp.net actually pertains to video functionality.  Feel free to retag to C# if you want a solution in C#.

Comment: @Jason Berkan, I removed the vb.net tag.  The OP never said anything about VB.NET and the question is for .NET, so any .NET answer should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL version of [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) has SDK examples of how to use it with VB.net in the "Developers\Project\MSVB\Example" folder of the 7z file. MediaInfo provides information on all kinds of media files.